# Difficulty converting this hibernate Criteria to JPA Criteria, issues with multiple associated entities

Tags: java, hibernate, criteriaquery, jpa

The hibernate criteria query I'm trying to change looks like this

```
Criteria crit = 
session.createCriteria(device.class)
.createCriteria("deviceConfigurationTemplate")
.createCriteria("deviceModel");
```

I want to simply change this to use JPA CriteriaQueries instead. The issue I'm having is how javax.persistence to create a query with multiple assoicated entities passed in as strings. I wanted to use JPA root criteria and multiselect them using the criteriaQuery like this

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Device> cq = cb.createQuery(Device.class);
Root<DeviceModel> model = cq.from(DeviceModel.class);
Root<"deviceConfigurationTemplate"> model2 = 
cq.from("deviceConfigurationTemplate");
cq.multiselect(model);
```

The issue here is you can't pass in a string as a parameter to the root object. I'm not sure how else to go about creating a query like this.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you try to pass a string as the type parameter? Once you join along an association, the resulting `Join` or `Path` should be parameterized with the association's target type.

Is the query supposed to be equivalent to `SELECT d.deviceConfigurationTemplate.deviceModel FROM Device d`? If so, the equivalent Criteria query would be:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<DeviceModel> criteria = cb.createQuery(DeviceModel.class);
Path<DeviceModel> model = criteria.from(Device.class).get("deviceConfigurationTemplate").get("model");
criteria.select(model);
```

With typing made a bit more explicit:

```
CriteriaQuery<DeviceModel> criteria = cb.createQuery(DeviceModel.class);
Root<Device> from = criteria.from(Device.class);
Path<ConfigurationTemplate> configTemplate = from.get("template");
Path<DeviceModel> model = configTemplate.get("model");
criteria.select(model);
```

You could also use `from.join()` instead.